# Any recommendation on fixing the equal method for my Java Calculator?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calculator

I am confused on approaching a proper fix for my equals onClick. Everytime I hit equals, the result returns the same input as the query. I was thinking of adding booleans for each (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division), but I believe I can do it straight on the onClickListener for equals. Is there any in built methods in Java I can utilize that can help with the calculations? Should I create a loop to create floats to store values depending on the length of query?

```
package com.example.tester;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //use to store button id's
    Button zero, juan, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine,
            brackets, add, subtract, multiply, divide, percent, clear, equal, period;

    //store id of textview
    TextView query, result;

    //Store value on buttons pressed
    String process;

    //set brackets to false
    boolean clickBracket = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        zero = findViewById(R.id.zero);
        juan = findViewById(R.id.juan);
        two = findViewById(R.id.two);
        three = findViewById(R.id.three);
        four = findViewById(R.id.four);
        five = findViewById(R.id.five);
        six = findViewById(R.id.six);
        seven = findViewById(R.id.seven);
        eight = findViewById(R.id.eight);
        nine = findViewById(R.id.nine);

        divide = findViewById(R.id.divide);
        multiply = findViewById(R.id.multiply);
        subtract = findViewById(R.id.subtract);
        add = findViewById(R.id.add);

        clear = findViewById(R.id.clear);
        brackets = findViewById(R.id.brackets);
        percent = findViewById(R.id.percent);
        equal = findViewById(R.id.equal);
        period = findViewById(R.id.period);

        query = findViewById(R.id.query);
        result = findViewById(R.id.result);

        //set Click
        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                query.setText("");
                result.setText("");
            }
        });

        zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "0");
            }
        });

        juan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "1");
            }
        });

        two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "2");
            }
        });

        three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "3");
            }
        });

        four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "4");
            }
        });

        five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "5");
            }
        });

        six.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "6");
            }
        });

        seven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "7");
            }
        });

        eight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "8");
            }
        });

        nine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "9");
            }
        });

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "+");
            }
        });

        subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "-");
            }
        });

        multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "x");
            }
        });

        divide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "÷");
            }
        });

        period.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + ".");
            }
        });

        percent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                process = query.getText().toString();
                query.setText(process + "%");
            }
        });

        brackets.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){

              if(clickBracket) {
                  process = query.getText().toString();
                  query.setText(process + ")");
                  clickBracket = false;
              }else {
                  process = query.getText().toString();
                  query.setText(process + "(");
                  clickBracket = true;
              }
            }
        });

        equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = query.getText().toString();

                process = process.replaceAll("×","*");
                process = process.replaceAll("%","/100");
                process = process.replaceAll("÷","/");


                String finalResult = process;


                result.setText(finalResult);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make these changes in your equal function.

```
equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                process = query.getText().toString();

                process = process.replaceAll("×","*");
                process = process.replaceAll("%","/100");
                process = process.replaceAll("÷","/");

                String formatedString = process;
                result.setText(evaluate(formatedString));
            }
        });
```

Add these two functions in your code and it will work like a magic

```
    private static String addSpaces(String exp) {
        exp = exp.replaceAll("(?<=[0-9()])[\\/]", " / ");
        exp = exp.replaceAll("(?<=[0-9()])[\\^]", " ^ ");
        exp = exp.replaceAll("(?<=[0-9()])[\\*]", " * ");
        exp = exp.replaceAll("(?<=[0-9()])[+]", " + ");
        exp = exp.replaceAll("(?<=[0-9()])[-]", " - ");
        exp = exp.replaceAll(" {2,}", " ");
        return exp;
    }

    public static Double evaluate(String expr) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
        String expression = addSpaces(expr);

        try {
            int indexClose = expression.indexOf(")");
            int indexOpen = -1;
            if (indexClose != -1) {
                String substring = expression.substring(0, indexClose);
                indexOpen = substring.lastIndexOf("(");
                substring = substring.substring(indexOpen + 1).trim();
                if (indexOpen != -1 && indexClose != -1) {
                    Double result = evaluate(substring);
                    expression = expression.substring(0, indexOpen).trim() + " " + result + " "
                            + expression.substring(indexClose + 1).trim();
                    return evaluate(expression.trim());
                }
            }

            String operation = "";
            if (expression.indexOf(" / ") != -1) {
                operation = "/";
            } else if (expression.indexOf(" ^ ") != -1) {
                operation = "^";
            } else if (expression.indexOf(" * ") != -1) {
                operation = "*";
            } else if (expression.indexOf(" + ") != -1) {
                operation = "+";
            } else if (expression.indexOf(" - ") != -1) { // Avoid negative numbers
                operation = "-";
            } else {
                return Double.parseDouble(expression);
            }

            int index = expression.indexOf(operation);
            if (index != -1) {
                indexOpen = expression.lastIndexOf(" ", index - 2);
                indexOpen = (indexOpen == -1) ? 0 : indexOpen;
                indexClose = expression.indexOf(" ", index + 2);
                indexClose = (indexClose == -1) ? expression.length() : indexClose;
                if (indexOpen != -1 && indexClose != -1) {
                    Double lhs = Double.parseDouble(expression.substring(indexOpen, index));
                    Double rhs = Double.parseDouble(expression.substring(index + 2, indexClose));
                    Double result = null;
                    switch (operation) {
                    case "/":
                        // Prevent divide by 0 exception.
                        if (rhs == 0) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        result = lhs / rhs;
                        break;
                    case "^":
                        result = Math.pow(lhs, rhs);
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result = lhs * rhs;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result = lhs - rhs;
                        break;
                    case "+":
                        result = lhs + rhs;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    if (indexClose == expression.length()) {
                        expression = expression.substring(0, indexOpen) + " " + result + " "
                                + expression.substring(indexClose);
                    } else {
                        expression = expression.substring(0, indexOpen) + " " + result + " "
                                + expression.substring(indexClose + 1);
                    }
                    return Double.valueOf(df.format(evaluate(expression.trim())));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0.0;
    }
```